# string in mmap shared memory c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, fork, shared-memory, mmap

My program is having segfault.

I'm trying access string from forks, but I can't even put data to shared memory.

**My code:**

```
static string * currentSessionIP;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    currentSessionIP = static_cast<string*>(mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
         MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0));
    *currentSessionIP = "";
}
```

There are no errors when mmap, but when I'm trying to assign something, it's segfaults.

How can I access to string from any fork(), and even change it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't treat an mmapped region as an `std::string` unless you first construct one there with [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html). Just treat it as a C string.

Comment: Your code does not compile. Can you provide a runnable testcase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't build the `std::string`, i.e. call it's constructor. The constructor is responsible for initializing the object data. Imagine `string` is implemented like this:

```
struct string {
    char* data;
    size_t length;
    // ...
};
```

You put this struct in valid memory with your cast, no problem there, but the value of the fields `data` and `length` is not initialized, so `data` points to a random address and `length` is garbage, thus when you use the string you get a crash. You must explicitly call the constructor, something like `currentSessionIP->string();` before using it, but that's impossible in `C++`. Instead you must use the [placement new](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) syntax, which combines the cast and the call to the constructor like this:

```
void * mem = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                  MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0));

currentSessionIP = new (mem) string;
```

This syntax is shorter and safer since you're sure the constructor is called. But you're still not done, because the `string` struct will be in shared memory, but that's just the "header" : the `data` has no reason to point inside your shared memory block.

By default `std::string` uses `std::allocator` which uses standard memory allocation, on your program heap. The solution is to use a custom allocator (template argument to `std::basic_string`) to ensure `data` always points in the shared memory.Your allocator will be called by the string object at initialization and when you resize the string.

Have a look [at this tutorial](http://www.drdobbs.com/creating-stl-containers-in-shared-memory/184401639) or at [boost interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess.html), meanwhile a very crude and incomplete implementation below, just to dive an idea:

```
// a very simple shared memory allocator
struct shared_alloc {
    typedef char value_type;
    typedef char* pointer;
    //... see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator

    pointer cur; // points to a free memory location
    shared_alloc() {
        cur = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                   MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0));
        // todo: lifecycle (free memory block sometime)
    }
    pointer allocate(size_t n) {
        pointer p = cur;
        cur += n; // todo bound checking
        return p;
    }
    void deallocate(pointer p, size_t n) {
        // todo: do something smart
    }
};

// an allocator object
shared_alloc alloc;

// a string with a custom allocator
typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, shared_alloc> shared_string;

// allocate shared mem for the string object (the header)
void * header_mem = alloc.allocate(sizeof(shared_string));

// create a string object at this location, and use our allocator for the data
shared_string * currentSessionIP =
  new( header_mem ) shared_string(alloc);
```

Comment: Maybe there is easier solution to store and modify from fork()'s string? Not especially mmap.
Idea: user connecting to daemon, im keeping his IP to variable. He asking for more connections and if his IP in variable, then daemon will allow it. Another user connected, but daemon busy and won't accept more connections from this user, while user1 connected.

Comment: `fork`ing it will work for read-only, if it changes in one process, you won't see it in other process (contrary to shared mem) - if it's not an issue for you, go. Other solution : since an ip address is a small object, message passing is a nice option. You could also consider multi-thread instead of multi-process?

Comment: I don't care how it will be realised, I'm just practicing C++.

Comment: Ok, then it's definitely a good exercise to go your way : strings in shared mem. Fork is more system-level than C++, so it might be easier but it won't teach you much about C++.

Comment: To be clear, I should move to `fork`ing or `thread`ing for my case? And I don't need shared memory in `thread`s, right?

Comment: Right, for threads you don't need shared mem since you keep the same address space. I can't give you a definite answer though: communication and sharing is simpler with threads, but forking is more secure (if a thread crash the whole process crash / if a process crash the fork'ed process are unaffected). Also if you have many tasks, multi-process eats more RAM than multi-thread. There are many pro/cons, it's not a simple question. Threading is usually simpler though. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` is an object, not just a contiguous memory buffer. You'd have to initialize the string or maybe use the placement new operator to create the string object.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `mmap` returns a pointer to uninitialized memory. It does not point to a string. Just because you cast the pointer to `string*` doesn't magically create a `std::string` at the location pointed to by `currentSessionIP`.

When you do `*currentSessionIP = ""`, you try to modify something that is not really a `std::string`, so this will segfault.

If you really want, you can create a string at that location using [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html), but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Why "new" bad in my case?

Comment: Read the link I gave in my answer. There might be issues with alignment, and you have to manually destruct the object (you cannot use `delete currentSessionIP`). What's more, data dynamically allocated inside the string class will be allocated on the heap anyway, and thus the whole attempt is doomed to fail.